# How to select and update in one query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to return a row:

```
.NET[tableReturn] = select top(1) * from [table] where x = 0 order by desc
```

but at the same time I need to update it:

```
update [table] set x = 1 where [id] = .NET[tableReturn].[id]
```

and need all data of this row

It is possible in the same query?

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2010** - we have 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2 and 2012 available, 2014 in the pipeline .... please update your title

Comment: Use a stored procedure.

Comment: thanks, is 2005 sorry

Comment: Strictly mathematically speaking, substitute your `.NET[tableReturn].[id]` variable from first equation into second and add round brackets ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Resolve this!

```
DECLARE @id int;
SET @id = (select top(1) id from [table] where [x] = 0 order by id desc);

select * from [table] where id = @id;
update [table] set [x] = 20 where id = @id;
```

:D

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
with cte as (select top(1) * from [table] where x=0 order by 1 desc)
update [table] set x=1 from cte join [table] c on c.id =cte.id;
```

Comment: return "(1 row(s) affected)" but not return row.

Comment: Try this


with cte as (select top(1) * from [table] where x=0 order by 1 desc)
update [table] set x=1 from cte join [table] c on c.id =cte.id
output inserted.*
;

Answer (score 0):

Use a stored procedure. In a stored procedure, you can execute as many queries as you desire.
Without it, you'll have to call multiple queries independently. 
 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query for updating the column with single query.

update [table] set x = 1 where x = (select cte.x from (select top(1) * from [table]  where x = 0 order by x desc) cte)

Note:- But the updated column should not be identity column